# Why does my excel stop responding when I try to run my VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

Updated my question. I put a flowchart and screenshots of my sheets so you guys can understand better.

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evsgm.png)

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyM8L.png)

When I start to run this, Excel stops responding. I can't seem to find where the bug is. I hope someone can help! I researched about VBA codes but I think something is still lacking?

```
Sub F110Loop()

Dim x As Integer 'current amount
Dim y As Integer
Dim d As Double 'delta between Disbursement date and Cheque Release date
Dim Current As Integer
Dim Least As Integer
Dim Dis As Worksheet
Dim Cheque As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Dis = wb.Sheets("Disbursements")
Set Cheque = wb.Sheets("Cheque Info")
wb.Activate

For x = 4 To 600
    Do While Dis.Cells(x, 9).Value > 1
        'IF same amount, get row number to get corresponding date, reference that date
        For y = 3 To 600
            If Dis.Cells(x, 6).Value = Cheque.Cells(y, 5).Value Then
                'THEN get delta
                Current = Dis.Cells(x, 4).Value -Cheque.Cells(y, 2)
                'IF current is less than the least delta
            ElseIf Current < Least Then
                'THEN update new value of delta
                Current = Least
            Else
                'copy paste the date (from the least delta row)
                Cheque.Cells(y, 2).Copy Destination:=Dis.Cells(x, 8)
            End If
        Next y
    Loop
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you bring some information about the data in the cells? It might be because Excel VBA has a limited amount of memory to work with so looping large worksheets can cause it to become inrespondent.

Comment: what is this line supposed to do? `Dis.Cells(x, 4).Value -Cheque.Cells(y, 2) = Current`

Comment: In addition to what @CharlesWilliams has already mentioned you should review a few lines: (1) `Dis.Cells(x, 4).Value -Cheque.Cells(y, 2) = Current`. I believe this should be `Current = Dis.Cells(x, 4).Value - Cheque.Cells(y, 2).Value`. Also, (2) the line `ElseIf Current < Least Then` will always compare `Current` to `0` because `Least` has never been assigned any value.

Comment: Hi @McBoman, thank you! The VBA considers two sheets with two 4x600 ranges.

Comment: Hi @arcadeprecinct, it is supposed to get the difference between two dates (encoding date vs. cheque release date). Then it stores that difference to Current. Then once the loop starts, the Current becomes the Least so that the current  is then compared to Least (the past Current) thus getting the minimum difference of dates, that will also satisfy the first condition -- same amount (adjacent cells).

Comment: Hi @charleswilliams, I already changed it to the second arrangement of codes, but it is still not responding. :(

Comment: @Chesca If you want to assign something to a variable, that variable has to be on the left side of the `=`. The assignment operator is not symmetrical.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you have an infinite loop because you never change Dis.Cells(x, 9)

```
Do While Dis.Cells(x, 9).Value > 1
' make no change to Dis.Cells(x, 9)
Loop
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding! It will not change even with "For x=4 to 600"?

Comment: @Chesca The `For x=4 to 600` cannot trigger the `next x` as the `do while` `loop` is repeating, consider changing that to an `If Dis.Cells(x,9).Value >1` `End If` instead

Answer (score 1):

you have to do something like:

```
x = 4
Do while Dis.Cells(x,9).value > 1
   x = x + 1
loop
```

Comment: Hi @nofey, how do I limit it so that it will continue to loop only until x=600? Thanks!!